# How to Suppress Warnings for Delphi 2009 Projects using MSBuild

Tags: batch-file, command-line, msbuild, delphi-2009

I managed to create a .bat for building my Delphi 2009 projects with MSBuild like this:

```
@SET BDS=C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0
@SET BDSCOMMONDIR=C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0
@SET FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
@SET FrameworkVersion=v2.0.50727
@SET FrameworkSDKDir=
@SET PATH=%FrameworkDir%;%FrameworkSDKDir%;%PATH%

msbuild "C:\MyProject.dproj" /t:build /p:config="Release";DCC_ExeOutput="C:\output\bin" > MyProject.log
```

Now I want to suppress warnings and retrieve only errors, if there are any. I tried theses approaches:

```
msbuild "C:\MyProject.dproj" /t:build /clp:ErrorsOnly /p:config="Release";DCC_ExeOutput="C:\output\bin" > MyProject.log
msbuild "C:\MyProject.dproj" /t:build /p:WarningLevel=0;config="Release";DCC_ExeOutput="C:\output\bin" > MyProject.log
```

But they still print warnings. So I found this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470(v=vs.110).aspx) where they explain how to attach a logger to the build process, and they give this example:

```
msbuild MyProject.proj /t:go /fileLogger
```

Since this option is for logging, I removed the `> MyProject.log`.
I tried in my project like below:

```
msbuild "C:\MyProject.dproj" /t:go /fileLogger /p:config="Release";DCC_ExeOutput="C:\Output\bin"
msbuild "C:\MyProject.dproj" /t:go /fileLogger
msbuild /t:go /fileLogger "C:\MyProject.dproj"
```

I receive this output for both (it's in portuguese, but it means **Unknown option** for /fileLogger):

[image]

May this error occurs due to my MSBuild.exe version? (I also have Visual Studio 2012 Professional installed).

The only way I could suppress warnings, was to change the build configuration for the project within Delphi 2009 IDE:

[image]

But I didn't want to change this for every project (there are hundreds).

Is there any other way to suppress warnings with MSBuild?
Or is there any way to change the Release config for all projects, changing *Output Warnings* to false (like I did within IDE)?

Comment: What the `msbuild /help` says? Maybe your `msbuild` version accepts only short switch version, i.e. `/fl` (or mandatory numbering, e.g. `/fl1`)?

Comment: On a side note, you should call the IDE's `rsvars.bat` script before calling msbuild, instead of using manual `@SET` instructions.

Comment: Another side note: It is always better spending time to fix code producing warnings then spending time on how to suppress those warnings.

Comment: @JosefZ unfortunately I tried both and the error persists. Look this for the [help output](http://puu.sh/mdOiU/2ddbacebbb.png). I compared my output with the [MSBuild Command-Line Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311(v=vs.110).aspx) and I found out my help doesn't show a /fileLogger, but it does show a /logger:<parameter> option, which is not in the MSBuild Command-Line Reference. I'm gonna try something with it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau actually I copied these SETs from rsvars.bat to my bat, because calling rsvars.bat was closing my compile bat. Then I learned I had to use ``call``, and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @Mofi you are completely right, we do usually fix warning issues when we build from IDE during development, but today it's impossible to fix for hundreds of programs, and we've just created this building bat because we need to rebuild all projects due to architecture changes, and we have projects in production without a fresh build since 2008, but a lot of them got compile errors, and we would like to write the error to a log file and associate with the project to analyze, but with ``> MyProject.log`` all output is written, and for this purpose we don't need warnings.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I ended up making a small application to open all .dproj files given a __start folder__ and setting **Output Warnings** to false for Release Config, then I achieved my goal, though this doesn't actually answer the question. Should I delete the question or answer with my final solution? Please, could you recommend me what to do, as you're more familiar with SO. Thanks!

Comment: You can do line code like `msbuild /target:Build /p:config=Release;DCC_Hints=false;DCC_Warnings=false;DCC_Quiet=true %ProjectName%`